# Inserting only 1 data into database PDO

Tags: php

Why is this not working please help me! how can i insert 1 data into database and also i want where in it :(

```
$Recipient = $_GET['Add_Friend'];
$Sender = $_SESSION['IsLogged'];

$query = 'INSERT INTO '.$DB_Table.' ('.$DB_Column['Friend_Requests'].') VALUES (:Sender) WHERE '.$User['Username'].'=:Recipient';
$run = $Database->prepare($query);
$run->execute
    (
    array(
            ':Sender' => $Sender,
            ':Recipient' => $Recipients
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT does not use the WHERE clause, because it adds data to a table, it doesn't filter anything. Your statement would probably look like this:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (someColumn)
VALUES ('some value')
WHERE otherColumn='other value';
```

What you probably want is:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (someColumn, otherColumn)
VALUES ('some value', 'other value');
```

Answer (score 0):

This `':Recipient' => $Recipients`

should be `':Recipient' => $Recipient`

as per `$Recipient = $_GET['Add_Friend'];`

you're using the wrong variable => `$Recipients` you've "*pluralized*" it.

Add `$Database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, including, and at the top of your file(s):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in order to troubleshoot/debug your code.